# modules are not showing in virtuemart

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am using joomla1.5 and virtuemart1.1.9 I have included the module in admin it displays in all page 
except the menu which i created for virtuemart. I am wondering why this happens. i have assigned the menu link directly gave it in index.php

```
<li><a href="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=28""><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/animal/images/shop.jpg" width="101" height="31" /></a></li>
```

Why there is no module displayed in virtuemart menu.

in index.php

```
<div id="mainBlock">
     <div id="col1">
     <div id="tab"></div>
      <div class="scrollbox">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="news" />
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />
     </div>
    <a href="index.php?option=com_joomgallery&Itemid=4"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/animal/images/photogallery.jpg" width="295" height="334" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
       <jdoc:include type="modules" name="shopmodule" />
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
     </div>
    </div>
```

but nothing displayed please check in [this](http://universalanimals.net/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=28)

Why the modules are not displayed in Virtuemart component page?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because you have given the menu directly in template. Just add the menu using the external URL feature in menu manager and check it.